# NextJS: Dynamic URL get auto redirected to root url(home page)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In NextJS I've created a dynamic page to fetch and display blog content, with the following URL
[https://example.com/blog/[blogId]](https://example.com/blog/%5BblogId%5D)

But when I try to access the URL on production the user gets redirected to root URL(home page) instead of the blog content page.

Below is my folder structure

```
pages

|__ blog

   |___ [blogId].tsx
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here?
PS: Locally this is working fine.

Comment: We need more details about the `[blogId].tsx` to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `[blogId]` as the variable part of your URL string, you have to make sure the data being served from your data source exactly matches.

`getStaticPaths` should generate an array of `blogID` in your case, something like this:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const pages = await getPathsForBlogs();
  return {
    paths: pages?.map(({ node }) => `/blog/${blogID}`) || [],
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

In `getStaticPages`, you'd ingest that stack of `paths` and Next will generate a page at each `blogID`. In this example, we send the data payload back to the component on the custom param `page`, which you'd desconstruct in your `/pages/blog.js` component.

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params, preview = false, previewData }) {
  const pageData = await getSingleActionPage(params.blogID, previewData);

  return {
    props: {
      preview,
      page: pageData ?? null,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  }
}
```